# Python – Print a character based on Unicode name stored as a string variable

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to make a script that prints a set of characters based on their Unicode names (What I mean by 'Unicode name' is that I want to use the character's 'description', not the codepoint).

I understood that the standard way to do it for a single character is to do:

```
>>> print('\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI}')
φ
```

My goal is to use a for loop that goes like this :

```
unicode_names = ['GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA', 'GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI']
for name in unicode_names:
    char_name = "{{{0}}}".format(name)
    print('\N' + char_name)
```

and the output would be:

```
α
φ
```

The problem is that whatever I try, (so far), I can’t print unicode character using a name stored as as string variable, be it by string concatenation or by using a `.format()` method.

```
phi = '\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI}'
phi_name = "{{{0}}}".format('GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI')
print(phi)
print(phi_name)
print('\N' + phi_name)
```

When I try I get this kind of SyntaxError :

```
    print('\N' + phi_name)
          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: malformed \N character escape
```

Should I use f-strings, or other kind of special strings?
Why `print('\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI}')` is not interpreted the same as `print('\N' + '{GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI}')` ?

Comment: What output are you hoping for?

Comment: I think the module you are looking for is `unicodedata`.

Comment: Sorry I did not precise but you got it right: my goal was to have the output `α
φ`. I didn't know about the unicode data library but it does the job. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a demo of how to use `unicodedata`:

```
import unicodedata
unicode_names = ['GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA', 'GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI']
for name in unicode_names:
    print (name, unicodedata.lookup(name))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`unicodedata.lookup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.lookup) function.

```py
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.lookup('GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI')
'φ'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
unicode_names = ['\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA}', '\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI}']
for name in unicode_names:
    print(f"{name}")
```